# Vaadin 14: sending data from a web component to server

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

How can i send data from client to server using html5 webcomponent

setting up data from server to client, is very easy, works like a charm
how ever cannot find solution to send data to server

Please assist, but Iam not going to use Lit or Polymer

```
#JavaScript
    class SimpleComponent extends HtmlElement {
      
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="test"/>";
        this._input = this.querySelector('#test');

         this._input.onchange = function() {
               *****  i want to send the value to server ****
          })
        

 

    }

    setInputValue(value) {
        this._input.value = value;
     }




}
customElements.define("simple-com",SimpleComponent);
```

Now Java at Server

```
    @Tag("simple-com")

       class SimpleComponent extends Component {

          public SimpleComponent() {

        }

           public void setValue(String value) {
                 getElement().callJsFunction("setValue",value);

   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer right now, but I can tell that the keyword to look for in Vaadin documentation would be `@ClientCallable`.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand  ClientCallable is not the answer. Trust i have tried.  The solution is to find the Javascript API, that calls the server, in polymer it's $.server, but i can not find it

Comment: Polymer or Lit has nothing to do with it. Note that it's `$server` and not `$.server`.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand, both $server and $.server are not defined on the client check the console.

Answer (score 2):

The main challenge compared to Polymer or LitElement is that an event handler defined using the pattern `innerElement.onchange = function() {}` will not be run with `this` referencing the custom element instance. This in turn means that trying to use `this.$server` won't work because `this` isn't pointing to the expected value even though `$server` is indeed present in the place where it's supposed to be.

The easiest way of fixing this is to change the code to use an arrow function (`() => {}`) instead of an explicit `function`. This works because arrow functions inherit `this` from the scope where the function is defined whereas explicit functions have `this` defined in different ways depending on how it is run. Another approach would be to store a reference to `this` in a separate variable (e.g. `let root = this`) and then reference that variable instead of `this` in the function (e.g `root.$server.doSomething()`).

Putting everything together, this is what the code looks like with my modifications to make everything work.

```js
class SimpleComponent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="test"/>';
    this._input = this.querySelector('#test');
    this._input.onchange = () => {
      this.$server.handleChange(this._input.value);
    };
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this._input.value = value;
  }
}
customElements.define("simple-com", SimpleComponent);
```